# Cell counting formula in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, count, excel-formula

I need to count the cells in column A with the word "Alex White", if in the same row in the cell in column D the text starts with "2012.02"? What could be the Excel 2010 formula for that?

None of the formulas below worked for me:

```
=SUM(IF(A2:A5000="Alex";1;0)+IF(D2:D5000="2012.02*";1;0))
=SUM(IF(AND((A2:A5000="Alex");(LEFT(D3;7)="2012.02"));1;0))
=SUMPRODUCT((D2:D5000="2012.02*");(A2:A5000="Alex"))
```

I'll be looking forward to your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array formulas of stephan and Excelll will work but I would like to point out that you could use `COUNTIFS`:

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A5000,"Alex White",D2:D5000,"2012.02*")
```

or the french version (one never knows if needed):

```
=NB.SI.ENS(A2:A5000;"Alex White";D2:D5000;"2012.02*")
```

Answer (score 3):

This one works:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(D2:D5000;7)="2012.02");--(A2:A5000="Alex"))
```

(If you want to match "Alex White", you obviously have to use this string instead). I assume that "2012.02" really is a string. If it is a date, you'd have to do something like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(D2:D5000>=DATE(2012;2;1));--(D2:D5000<=DATE(2012;3;0));--(A2:A5000="Alex"))
```

Comment: @Artiso: In Excel `=-TRUE` is `-1`, hence `--TRUE` is `1`. And `=-FALSE` is `0` (try it in Excel). Hence, the `--` converts `TRUE` to `1` and `FALSE` to `0`. `SUMPRODUCT` then just sums `0`s and `1`s. It's a nifty trick (aka hack) that is quite useful for these "sumif"-formulas.

Answer (score 1):

Enter the following as an array formula by pressing Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

```
=SUM(IF(A2:A5000="Alex White",IF(LEFT(D2:D5000,7)="2012.02",1,0),0))
```

Comment: For your regional settings, just replace my commas with semicolons.